Retriving values to mapbox color values from nested geoJSON object
I am building a app with mapbox, and the backend will return a GeoJSON like this:
{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "heatmap": {
                    "argValue": 3.119083813173218,
                    "zoneLabel": "demo",
                    "metricAvg": 2.589442015839714,
                    "difference": 0.5296417973335039
                }
            },
            "id": "abcedd
        },

geometry was skipped, but when i tried to add stops to the color with the following code:
const heatmapLayer:FillLayer = {
  id: 'heatmap',
  maxzoom: MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL,
  type: 'fill',
  paint: {
    'fill-color': [
      'interpolate',
      ['linear'],
      ['get', 'heatmap',['get','argValue']],
      3.0, 'rgba(33,102,172,0)',
      3.1, 'rgb(103,169,207)',
      3.2, 'rgb(253,219,199)',
      3.3, 'rgb(253,219,199)'
    ],
    'fill-opacity': 0.4,
    'fill-antialias': true
  }
};

However it only render the color black instead of other colors, is there anything I've done wrong?
It didnt work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
